# error message of WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): CUDA is installed, but device gpu0 is not available

Tags: theano, nvidia, theano-cuda

I have installed theano using pip install theano, which was finished successfully. After typing import theano, I got the following warning message

```
WARNING (theano.sandbox.cuda): CUDA is installed, but device gpu0 is not available  (error: Unable to get the number of gpus
```

What does it mean and how to resolve this issue? Thanks.